# how to get the value of each character in a string from a given list of values in Python3?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list

I am trying to find the values of all the characters in a string(the strings are all lowercase letters) by a given list of values. For example:

```
number_list = [1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7]
string = 'abc'
```

The output should be like this:

```
[1,3,1]
```

The number_list contains exactly 26-numbers. The first number in the output is 1 because  'a' is the first alphabet and the 1st number in the number_list is 1. 'b' is the second alphabet so the second number in the number_list is 3. Similarly, it is for 'c'

Another example:

```
number_list = [1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7]
string = 'zaba'
```

The ouput should be:

```
[7,1,3,1]
```

The first number in the output is 7 because z is the last alphabet and the last-number in the number_list in 7. Similarly are the rest.

How can I do something like this using Python 3.x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the string only contains lowercase alphabet

```
[number_list[ord(i)-97] for i in string]
```

This will work

Comment: or `[number_list[ord(i)-ord('a')] for i in string]`

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `string` module:

```
import string
number_list = [1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7]
a = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, number_list))
s = 'abc' 
print([a[i] for i in s])
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 1]
```